# Conceptually(not algebraically), why do I get a quadratic equation when I subtract a linear equation form a quadratic equation.

Tags: quadratics

While simultaneously solving a quadratic equation and a linear equation, I noticed that their intercepts are actually equal to the x intercepts of another quadratic function. I find it hard to grasp that subtracting a linear equation from a quadratic equation results in a symmetric curve(parabola).

I understand that the result of the subtraction will give me a polynomial of degree 2 which forms a parabola, but why?

Comment: I think that in order to answer this question, we would need to know what exactly makes something "quadratic" intuitively. What do you *expect* to happen when one adds a linear function to a quadratic one that might "ruin" the property of being quadratic?

Comment: Both linear, and quadratic functions are changing according to different 'rules'. It just feels weird that their subtraction can produce something symmetric. I know about the vertex form(just completed quadratics in college)

Comment: Also, do you know what the [vertex form](https://blog.prepscholar.com/vertex-form-parabola) of a quadratic is?

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I think the thing to nail down then is what exactly is the "rule" that a quadratic function follows? Once you have that nailed down, you should find that linear functions actually follow the same rule that quadratic functions do, and adding any two such function is going to make it so that this rule will still be followed.

Comment: One rule that characterizes a quadratic function is the property of linear differences (or constant second-order differences), which is what the answer given below describes

Comment: THANK YOU!!! This seems to be a whole new way of thinking about functions. Can I get references for further reading(its hard to find stuff that's my level).

Comment: If you like that, then you'll love calculus. In fact, the rule that is more typically used in this kind of way is that of the [derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative) of a quadratic function. Instead of looking at the difference between $f(x)$ and $f(x + 1)$, we look at the *slope* of the function $f$ at the point $x$. It turns out as just as these differences change linearly, so does the slope change linearly.

Comment: As for a reference: this kind of analysis usually appears in the study of difference equations, which is unfortunately rarely presented at the high school level. [This wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_difference_equation) gives some of the broader context. The specific usage on quadratic functions [is described here](https://www.radfordmathematics.com/algebra/sequences-series/difference-method-sequences/quadratic-sequences.html) in a way that I think should be "at your level".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of looking at it is through finite differences. A quadratic function has the property that successive differences follow a linear progression. For example, with $f(n) = n^2 + n + 1$:

```
n  f(n)  difference
-------------------
0    1  
          2
1    3  
          4
2    7
          6
3   13
          8
   ...
```

A linear function has the property that successive differences are constant. Thus, adding a linear function to a quadratic function will shift the differences of the latter without disturbing their linearity.

The argument in the previous paragraph relies on an understanding that "constant + linear = linear", so in fact you can see that you can use the same reasoning inductively for adding polynomials of any degree.

Answer (score 0):

A higher level understanding of this could come from the study
of affine geometry. In affine geometry all conics are either
ellipses, hyperbolas, or parabolas, and are not changed in
character by any affine transformation. Your notion of

> subtracting a linear equation from a quadratic equation

is a special case of an affine transformation and and hence transforms a parabola to another parabola.